# g++ and double precision

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain to me why executing the following code returns that (1./3.)*3. is equal to 1.? I was assuming that the rounding would prevent such an equality but apparently it doesn't work that way. Any explanation?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double x = 1./3.;
  double y = 3.*x;
  std::cout.precision(30);
  std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
  std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
  if (y == 1.)
    std::cout << "Equality!" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Not equality." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It returns:

$ g++ test_dp.cpp -o test_dp.exe

$ ./test_dp.exe

x = 0.333333333333333314829616256247

y = 1

Equality!

Comment: Maybe a better question for mathoverflow.  Or for the author to reread ;)

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash  This is definitely NOT a question for mathoverflow.   Maybe stackoverflow.

Comment: @DavidG. was a joke (maybe not a very good one)... (1./3.)*3. seems like math to me

Comment: Yes you are right @MartinYork and I agree with you, this is why I expected the code I added to return "Not equality" but in fact, it returns "Equality!" so why ?

Comment: @user2509143 Sorry did not read. It's because of the bit pattern of the fraction part of a floating point number (note IEEE 754) and the way of multiplication is done. `1/3` bit pattern is (the fraction part) `010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010` (i.e. its bit alternate 0 and 1 for the fraction. Now if you multiply by three (if you do it by hand the pit pattern becomes `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (i.e they all become 1. But you have to remember that we are dealing with non exact computation and how IEEE 754 maths work.

Comment: So when you do the multiplication you have a choice for the last digit that falls off the end. Do you round that up or down. I assume it rounds up which then has a cascading affect and makes the value exactly 1.

Comment: Also because you are using constants. The compiler can easily simplify that expression at compile time. Sub/Expression cancelling is an easy optimization done at compile time. You have the expression `1/3*3`. The compiler can easily optimize that to `1` by cancelling out the divide by 3 and the multiply by 3.

Comment: Just looked up IEEE 754. Found a non conical source. But the default behavior of IEEE 754 is to round to the "nearest" value after performing an operation (including multiplication). In this case any overflow of the end are all 1 so rounding up is what is expected. In this situation we are going to round up as there is an overflow. So you would expect a rounding up in this situation.

Comment: @MartinYork: you don't have to invoke compile-time constant folding to explain this. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful answers, do you know a tool that could simply display the binary representation (let's say with something like a std::cout for example or more complex if need be) ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `double` type is [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) compliant, the hexadecimal representation of 1.0/3.0 is `3FD5555555555555`. This is not exactly 1/3. It breaks down as:

- Sign = 0 (i.e. number is positive)
- Biased exponent = `3FD` (i.e. exponent = -2)
- 53-bit Mantissa = `15555555555555` (the leading `1` is implied)

Multiplying `15555555555555` by 3 gives `3FFFFFFFFFFFFF`. To squeeze this into 53 bits, we have to discard the least significant bit, which (in the default rounding mode for most environments) means that the mantissa is "rounded to even": trailing binary `01` goes to `0`, and trailing binary `11` goes to `100` (which means that carries may be propagated). In this case, the carry propagates all the way up to the most significant bit, leaving `40000000000000` in the mantissa. We want bit 52 to be the most significant bit, so we shift this down to `10000000000000` and increase the exponent by 2. The end result is `3FF0000000000000`, or exactly 1.0.

So your program is behaving correctly -- an inexact result multiplied by a small integer gives you an exact result. But one could take the view that this is more by luck than judgment :-)